# APK Expansion on Finish Download

Tags: android, apk, apk-expansion-files

I am currently working on publishing an app (using Cocos2d-x) on google play and since the file size is larger than 50MB, I have to use the expansion file.

I refer to this page and the sample given at http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Currently, everything works fine. 
My problem is that when it finishes downloading the expansion file and verified the file, clicking the OK button will close the app.

How can I resume my main app?
Reopening the app again will run the game perfectly since the expansion file has been downloaded.

I would like it to resume the main app right away after downloading the expansion. I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution from a help elsewhere.
Hope this will come in handy.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/40369

http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-launch-pending-intent.html